# Laravel 5.1/5.6 How to send a url in email blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.5

I am using Mail::send function to send emails to my end users with dynamically generated links in them  Below is my sample code for the function -
    $myemail = "some email adderess";
    $myurl = "some url that will be emailed";

```
Mail::send('emails.mybladetemplate', ['myemail' => $myemail] , function ($message) use ($myemail){

$message->subject('Your favorite links');
$message->from('someone@company.com', 'Company');
$message->to($myemail);
});
```

I am having trouble passing $myurl to the blade template and publishing it.  I even used HTML{{ }} in my blade template but no success.  I have tested Mail::send with other templates and it works fine.  Just not when I pass the variables.

Comment: Add a comma for the `use` portion and add `$myurl`

Comment: @DavidNguyen  ['myemail' => $myemail] here or use ($myemail) ?   Also how can I display it in the blade template?

Answer (score 0):

Added ['myemail' => $myemail, 'myurl' => $myurl] and use ($myemail, $myurl) to solve for it.

Comment: That would fix your error indeed. If you work with e-mail templates there are api's out there handle all the e-mail generation for you. [Json2Email](https://json2email.com) is one but there are others as well.